# How to upload file in seleniumBase if there is no button and [type="file"] are available

Tags: python, selenium, seleniumbase

I have below dom elements
[image]

I have tried choose_file but it is not working in my case, I have also tried the send_keys() method but still not working.

Selenium base support the choose_file() method if the dom element is type="file" but in my case that is missing.

Looking for any help

Comment: Are you sure no element matching `input[type='file']` exists on that page?

Comment: @Prophet thanks for your time, Yes i am sure there is no `input[type='file']`

Comment: Well, without such element I do not know how to upload file with Selenium. Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet Please let me know if you got any workaround

Comment: there are 23 `input[type='file']` elements on that page

Comment: Yes but not for that element which I want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249721/discussion-between-krupal-vaghasiya-and-prophet).

Comment: @Prophet Please ping me if you got any solution

Comment: I see no difference between all those elements. I guess each one of them is for uploading files to different sections on that page, but I can't distinguish between them to see what input belongs to what section.

Comment: What else i can do for that? any way to overcome from that?

Comment: As I see - nothing. If you were working for that company you could ask frontend developers to add some unique attributes for those elements.

Comment: Can we upload file anyhow using pure python?

Comment: There are more tools / libraries, but I'm not so familiar with them. I'm sorry